# Binding object to the Blazor routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I want to bind my page URL with an object that represents a request filter(productName, categoryId .etc). How can I bind them in blazor with query string?

`@page "/products/{filter}"
...
@code {`

```
public Filter filter = new Filter()
{
    SearchedName = "Test",
    CategoryId = 1
};
```

}

I want something like that. In Asp.Net Core I am able to bind an object with form and query string but in blazor I have some trouble. Can you give solution for this. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that currently you can't pass complex content as a Route parameter.

Instead you should use Component Attribute Parameter as this code snippet demonstrate:

In a parent component instantiate a variable of type Filter and assign it to the Filter Attribute Property of the Products component

`<products Fitler = "@AFilterInstance" />`, in which you should define a parameter property that will store the passed value like this:

```
[Parameter]
public Filter Filter { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps...